# remove extra space between words in html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm using html/css and  text-align: justify; When I use the text below the 2nd line has a big gap between words . The rest of the stuff is fine.

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the <a href="http://example.com"> example </a>and Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the lorem. I'm also printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic </p>
```

I'm getting many extra spaces between each word in this line 2nd line. How ca I fix it ? 
Like this:

```
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
    text   of    the   lorem.   I'm   also   printing   and    typesetting     industry.   
    Lorem Ipsum has been
```

The

Comment: this is the justify alignement

Comment: Justified means that it takes up the whole line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`text-align: justify;` spreads out a line to make sure there's no gap at the end of it. To do this, it has to add extra spaces in the middle.

If you don't want this, don't do `text-align: justify;`, or tell us what you want it to do? Perhaps you want `text-align: left`?

:)

Comment: OHH! I get it now Yes!! Sorry and thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.b { 
  word-spacing: -3px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is some text. This is some text.</p>
<p class="b">This is some text. This is some text.</p>
</body>
</html>
```